# bash script – MySQL commands and variables

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, shell-scripting, nextcloud

I have a bash script who automate a Nextcloud server installation.

To run MySQL commands I use the mysql -e command

```
user@hostname:~$ mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE ‘NextcloudDataBaseName’"
```

I would like store db name, user name, password, etc. In variables

How write mysql -e commands with variables ?

```
user@hostname:~$ mysql -e "CREATE USER ‘$UserName’@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ‘$UserPass’"

user@hostname:~$ mysql -e "CREATE USER ${UserName}@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${UserPass}"
```

The two command above don’t run

Error message with user password (test password) :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'qwerty1234'
```

This syntax seems to work :

```
user@hostname:~$ mysql -e "CREATE USER '${DbUserName}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DbUserPass}'"
```

Simple quotes around variable names but is this the best syntax, the best practice ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: BEWARE:  If there is a quite in the password, bash will give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (with *here-doc*):

```
mysql<<EOF
CREATE USER '$UserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$UserPass';
EOF
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Thanks Gilles everything works with Here Doc.

Merci beaucoup tout fonctionne avec Here Doc et c'est plus propre !